# Refresh ExpandableListView when adding data: keep state

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` filled using a custom adapter using `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. I can add new data in a new activity, and then I have to refresh the list. When the list is refreshed, I want to keep the same groups expanded.

The new entries can be added at any point in the list. We can add new groups or just new childs.

Right now I'm using:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The list refreshes, but the state is not the same. In example, if I have three groups: G1 expanded, G2 not expanded, G3 expanded, and I add a new group G4 between G2 and G3, then G4 gets the G3 state since it takes its position. Is there any way to keep the state automatically or I have to do it manually in my adapter?

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Adding some code.

This is my adapter:

```
public class StopsInnerExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> groups; // Dates.
private ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> children; // HashMap has stop ID, image and price.
private Context context;

public StopsInnerExpandableListAdapter (Context ctx, ArrayList<String> groups, 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> children) {
    context = ctx;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        // Inflate child's view.
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_row, null);
    }

    // Get the stop data and use it to fill the child's views.
    HashMap<String, String> child = children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);

    ...

    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return children.get(groupPosition).size();
}

public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    if (convertView == null) {
        // Inflate group's view.
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_subgroup, null);
    }

    String date = groups.get(groupPosition);

    TextView dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_date);
    dateView.setText(date);

    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return true;
}

public void updateData(ArrayList<String> groups,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> children) {
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
}
}
```

In my activity I do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stop_list);

    mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);

    model = new MyModel(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ListEntries entries = model.getEntries();

    if(adapter == null){
        // Sets the adapter that provides data to the list.
        adapter = new StopsInnerExpandableListAdapter(this, entries.getDates(), entries.getChilds());
        mExpandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        adapter.updateData(entries.getDates(), entries.getChilds());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I added some code to the post :)

Comment: have u find any solution for this ?

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani Solution posted

Answer (score 2):

The `ExpandableListView` is not re-expanding correctly because you are not using stable IDs. Using stable IDs will fix the problem for you.

While you did enabled stable IDs via here:

```
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

You still need to actually return stable IDs with the `getGroupId()` and `getChildId()` methods.  Returning the `groupPosition` and `childPosition` respectively does not qualify as stable IDs.

To be a stable ID means the value returned will be unique across the entire data set. Additionally, the value returned will be the same no matter what the position of a given item is.  For instance, lets say you are storing People.  Every person has a unique SSN.  That would be an excellent stable ID to return with `getChildId()`. Eg, If John Smith is at position 2, 4 (group, child) and then is later moved to position (3, 1)...his stable ID (or SSN) will still be the same.  Returning only position numbers can not guarantee this.